# my login cannot go to the next page

Tags: php

I don't know what is the problem with my login page. After I logged in it is still in the login page.

I have a table staff

```
CREATE TABLE `staff` (                    
          `staffid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,         
          `password` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,    
          `staffname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   
          `staffemail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
          `level` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,            
          PRIMARY KEY (`staffid`)                 
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

with two level. 1 for staff 2 for admin after entering staffid and password the page should go to the page base on their level.

1.login.php

```
<? session_start(); ?>
<title>Inventory Management System</title>
<center>
 <form name="form1" method="POST" action="logincheck.php">
    <table width="468" height="328" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="124" colspan="2">
        <?php include "header.php"?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="184" height="65" 
        align = "right">No Kakitangan</td>
        <td width="274"><label for="staffid"></label>
        <input type="text" name="staffid" id="staffid"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="184" height="60" 
        align = "right">Kata Laluan</td>
        <td><label for="password"></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="42" colspan="2" 
        align = "center"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In">
        <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Batal"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
    <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1"/>
    </p>

  </form>
</center>
```

2.logincheck.php

```
<?php require_once('Connections/sqlconnection.php'); ?>
<? session_start(); ?>
<?php
    $staffid = isset($_POST['staffid']) ? $_POST['staffid'] : "";
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : "";
    //get user info from the database base on staffid and password
    mysql_select_db($database_sqlconnection, $sqlconnection);
    $sql = "select s.* from staff s where s.staffid = '".$staffid."' and
    s.password = '".$password."'" ;
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql,$sqlconnection) or die(mysql_error());
    $rowUsr = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
    $cnt = mysql_num_rows($result1);
    $level = '';
    //if staffid exists
    if($cnt > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['staffid']=$staffid;
        $level = $rowUsr['level'];
        //compare the password
        if ($level == 1)
             $_SESSION['userlevel']='staff';
        else if ($level == 2)
                  $_SESSION['userlevel']='admin';
        else $_SESSION['userlevel']='err';
             echo "<script> location.href='index.php'; </script>";
    }
    else {
          echo "<script> alert('Sila masukkan semula. No Kakitangan atau Kata Laluan salah.');</script>";
    echo "<script> location.href='login.php'; </script>";
    }
    mysql_free_result($result1);
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also, read up on SQL injection. Your code is very vulnerable. I could submit a password along the lines of `' OR '1' ='1` and be logged in as your admin user.

Comment: so now i have to use PDO? i have never use that and i'm confused where should i change the code even i have read the tutorial. **please guide me**

Comment: Yes, you should use PDO, or at least MySQLi. The mysql_* functions are being removed eventually.

Comment: still not working and have a lots of errors..

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the internal result pointer to the beginning with [mysql_data_seek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php). Try using:

```
mysql_data_seek($result1, 0);
```

Use:

```
$rowUsr = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
mysql_data_seek($result1, 0);
$cnt = mysql_num_rows($result1);
```

What's happening is that the pointer is left at the end of the dataset once you do `mysql_fetch_array`. `mysql_data_seek($result1, 0);` will return it to the beginning.

Comment: it is still not working and now there is an error 
**mysql_data_seek():Offset 0 is invalid for MYSQL result index 4(or the query is unbuffered).**

Comment: I suspect your query is not returning any results then.

Comment: Take out the code I gave you and write `echo $cnt;` after `$level = '';` What do you get?

Comment: SCREAM:Error suppresion ignored for